# Coral Dev Board doesn't start after attaching the environmental sensor board

Tags: google-coral

I have followed steps 1 & 2 as described at https://coral.ai/docs/enviro-board/get-started/#1-attach-the-sensor-board. Attached sensor board in such a way that it is right on top of the fan using the extension. **NOT** the other way. When I start the Coral device is twitches for a few sec and stops.

I used the power adapter with enough voltage and amps. Even tried with the latest Mac Book Pro charger to make sure Coral device is NOT starving for the power.

Not sure I am missing any. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to connect an HDMI monitor with the Dev Board to see what is happening on the screen ?
Do you see any error or logs on the serial console?
Is the board working fine without connecting the Enviro board ?

Comment: @Manoj 
1) Issue is DevBoard doesn't even start when I connect the Env Sensor Board. I tried connecting to the monitor using HDMI, but I didn't see anything during startup.
2) Yes, Dev Board is working without env sensor board.

Comment: Please confirm that you have the Dev board and not the Dev board mini ?

Comment: I have Dev Board. Not mini.